# Creating a simple Oracle SQl trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for a fake database. Suppose there
is a derived attribute named “total_loan” for BANK-BRANCH that is used to maintain the total amount of loan at each branch. I am trying to  design a trigger to maintain this derived attribute. My trigger thus seems to stop my load.sql script shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE a2_bankbranch (
name           VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
branch_num     VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
address        VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
routing_code   VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
total_loan     NUMBER(38),
FOREIGN KEY(routing_code) REFERENCES a2_bank(routingcode),
PRIMARY KEY(branch_num, routing_code)
);
@trig.sql

INSERT INTO a2_bankbranch VALUES
( 'ASB', '5', '3 gladstone rd', '123456', '');
INSERT INTO a2_bankbranch VALUES
( 'ASB', '4', '28 stevee rd', '123456', '');

CREATE TABLE a2_loan (
loan_num       CHAR(10)  PRIMARY KEY,
type           VARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
amount         NUMBER(38)  NOT NULL,
contract_date  DATE          NOT NULL,
branch_num     VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
routing_code   VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(routing_code) REFERENCES a2_bank(routing_code),
Foreign KEY(branch_num) REFERENCES a2_bankbranch(branch_num)
);

INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '323', 'Mortgage', '2000000', TO_DATE('11-03-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456');
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '33', 'Car', '2000', TO_DATE('12-08-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '3243', 'Pesonal', '875', TO_DATE('14-06-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
INSERT INTO a2_loan VALUES
( '6', 'Mortgage', '400500', TO_DATE('11-06-1994', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), '5', '123456' );
```

My trigger is shown below, the initial insert is not functioning and I am not sure what to put in my WHERE and SET lines for updating and deletion
The trig.sql is shown below

```
-- Create a trigger that will update the total loan amount
--that each bank brach may have

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ttl
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OF total_loan ON a2-bankbranch
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
UPDATE a2_loan
SET total_loan = total_loan + :NEW.amount
WHERE branch_num = :NEW.bank_num;
ELSIF UPDATING THEN
UPDATE a2_loan
SET total_loan = total_loan + amount
WHERE
ELSE --deleting
UPDATE a2_loan
WHERE
END;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've tagged this for SQL Server and Oracle, two different databases.  Which one are you actually using?  I assume Oracle.  I'm guessing that the SQL Server tag should be removed.  Your data types don't make sense-- you're storing numeric values in `varchar2` columns.  I would expect that you'd want the trigger to be defined on the `loan` table but there is no obvious way to tie a loan to a branch in your data model.

Comment: Yes sorry using Oracle. As you can see I am a little bit lost, the end result of the trigger should be that if I change the loan amount that a particular customer has the database will automatically update the total loan amount given out by the bank_branch that the customer is a member at. Does that help?

Comment: How do you know what branch a customer is a member of?  I don't see anything in your data model that tells us how to map either a loan or a customer to a branch.  Do you expect that the answer requires all of the tables that you posted?  If not, paring things down to just the tables of interest would make the question clearer.

Comment: Sorry so when a new loan is created the database needs to update the bank_branch attribute total_loan. I will quickly edit the code to only have the tables that are necessary

Comment: Which `a2_bankBranch` row should be updated when `loan_num` 6 is added?  Your data model appears to be missing a way to indicate that a particular loan is owned by a particular branch.  I'm guessing that you would want to add `branch_num` and `routing_code` to the `a2_loan` table as a foreign key to `a2_bankBranch` to indicate that relationship.  Unless a loan can apply to more than one branch.

Comment: `ON a2-bankbranch` should be `ON a2_bankbranch` or is it a typo ?

Comment: Another thing that I saw, use proper columns types you are doing mathematical operations on varchar columns, which makes oracle do implicit convertions which can be slow on huge data

Comment: One more thing the first two insert are inserting empty on total_loan field is that right ?

Comment: That is where I would like my trigger to automatically update those values Jorge

Comment: The foreign key declaration that you added isn't valid-- it would have thrown an error if you actually ran it.  You'd need to use both columns from the primary key in the foreign key.  But yes, that's the right direction.  Now if you can fix your data types so that numeric values are stored in numeric columns, that will make life much easier.  Doing arithmetic with strings like "$20000" rather than the number 20000 is painful.

Comment: Not sure quite what you mean with the foreign key deceleration? I have changed the total_loan and amount to be NUMBER(38)

Comment: If you ran the `CREATE TABLE a2_loan` statement you posted, you would get an error that there was no matching primary or unique constraint in the parent `a2_bankbranch` table.  The foreign key needs to be on both `branch_num` and `routing_code`.  Your `insert` statements should also be inserting numbers rather than strings for the numeric columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the standard caveat.  You would never use a trigger to do this sort of thing in the real world.  In the real world, you probably shouldn't store a denormalized total in the first place.  If you do, you would want to use a materialized view to maintain it.

That being said, I expect that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER your_trigger_name
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON a2_loan
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING 
  THEN
    UPDATE a2_bankbranch
       SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) + :new.amount
     WHERE routing_code = :new.routing_code
       AND branch_num   = :new.branch_num;
  END IF;

  IF UPDATING
  THEN
    UPDATE a2_bankbranch
       SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) - :old.amount
     WHERE routing_code = :old.routing_code
       AND branch_num   = :old.branch_num;

    UPDATE a2_bankbranch
       SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) + :new.amount
     WHERE routing_code = :new.routing_code
       AND branch_num   = :new.branch_num;
  END IF;

  IF DELETING
  THEN
    UPDATE a2_bankbranch
       SET total_loan = nvl(total_loan,0) - :old.amount
     WHERE routing_code = :old.routing_code
       AND branch_num   = :old.branch_num;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Just to reinforce why you don't use triggers: Sally inserts $5 loan.  Trigger sets total loans of branch from $100 to $105.  Before Sally commits her insert (making it visible to other users), Jenny inserts a $10 loan.  Jenny's trigger (which can't see Sally's loan) sets total branch loans from $100 to $110.  Jenny commits.  Branch total is $110.  Moments later, Sally commits.  Branch total becomes $105.  Actual sum of loans, including both Sally's and Jenny's, is $115.

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick - That would be an issue with some potential implementations of this sort of trigger.  It wouldn't be an issue with this specific trigger because two sessions can't lock the same row to update it at the same time.  In this implementation, Jenny's session would block until Sally's session commits.  The issue would be that if Sally's session hung for any reason, no one would be able to process loans for that branch until the DBA identified and killed the session.  That could be a catastrophic limiter to the application's scalability.

Comment: We're both a bit off: when Jenny issues her insert, her update would be blocked until Sally commits.  Sally's commit will update grand total to $105. Once Sally's commit is issue, Jenny's session will be unblocked.  It will, however, still set the total incorrectly ($110 not $115).  There are workarounds for this - the trigger can first select the branch row for update (waiting for excl lock on it), then issue update of total_loan = total_loan+:new.amount.  Point being - triggers get complicated... and even done correct (maintaining data integrity), will have scalability issues from locking.

Comment: Mea culpa.  Update only reads current value after lock is cleared.  You're right - the totals are updated correctly, only issue is locking.  Committed cardinal sin of not taking 2 min to check my assumptions before posting.